# method rules overloading explanation in java

Tags: java, overloading

I try to understand overloading rules which uses java compiler.

it is too hard for me.

```
public class Main {

    public static void var(Long x) {
        System.out.println("Long");
    }

    public static void var(int... x) {
        System.out.println("int... x");
    }


    public static void main(String... args) {
          var(5);
    }
}
```

output:

```
int...
```

In Internet I found next rules:

> 1. Primitive Widening > Boxing > Varargs.
> 2. Widening and Boxing (WB) not allowed.
> 3. Boxing and Widening (BW) allowed.
> 4. While overloading, Widening + vararg and Boxing + vararg can only be used in a mutually exclusive manner i.e. not together.
> 5. Widening between wrapper classes not allowed

but I cannot apply this rules to this code behaviour.

Can you help me?

my **wrong** version:

boxing `int` -> `Integer` and widening to `Long`

### Additional question

```
public class Main {

    public static void var(Object x) {
        System.out.println("Object");
    }

    public static void var(int... x) {
        System.out.println("int... x");
    }


    public static void main(String... args) {
          var(5);
    }
}
```

output:

```
object
```

Comment: Well, the answer is in the question: *Widening and Boxing (WB) not allowed*. To call the method taking a Long, the int 5 would have to be widened to a long, then boxed to a Long. And that is not allowed.

Comment: boxing int -> Integer and widening to Long

Comment: Boxing and Widening (BW) allowed.

Comment: Widening between wrapper classes not allowed. Anyway, the rules are extremely complex, and the source of truth is the JSL.

Comment: for me corresponds part of jls super extra extremely complicated

Comment: I agree. That's why I generally avoid using such overloaded methods. Using distinct names makes everything much clearer, and don't confuse developers.

Comment: @JB Nizet Unfortunately I cannot avoid these quesions in scjp exam(. Hence I find ways to remember it.

Comment: Ah, OK. I didn't realize this was for a certification exam, and not a question based on an actual programming problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> boxing `int` to `Integer` and widening to `Long`

Although `int` to `Integer` boxing is fine, but `Integer` to `Long` is not a valid widening. `Long` is not supertype of `Integer`. So that's not valid. One option is *widening* followed by *boxing*. But such conversion is not allowed in Java. So the only option that is left is using varargs.

Comment: I noticed one more strange behaviour. can you explain it ?(added in topic)

Comment: @gstackoverflow That is boxing followed by widening. `Integer` to `Object` is a valid widening.

Comment: boxing+widening - third, but varargs - in first step

Comment: @gstackoverflow Just remember one thing while method overloading -> `varargs` comes last. Compiler will always first try exact match, then widening, then boxing, then boxing followed by widening, and then varargs. The rules are there in JLS.

Comment: Are there exist **vararg + widening** and **vararg+boxing**

Comment: I want to create own list of rules and test it

Comment: @gstackoverflow Can you please go through some book or JLS? Explaining all the rules here is really next to impossible for me.